# What does "the bulls" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

I'm reading *The Witchcraft Delusion in Colonial Connecticut, 1647-1697* by John M. Taylor, (originally published in 1908, reprinted in 1971) and I'm not quite understanding what is meant by "the bulls" in this section of text on pages 10 and 11:

> …the famous and infamous manual of arguments and rules of procedure for the detection and punishment of witches, compiled by the German Inquisitors Krämer and Sprenger (Institor) in 1489, buttressed on the bull of Pope Innocent VIII; (this was the celebrated *Witch Hammer*, bearing on its title page the significant legend, "*Not to believe in witchcraft is the greatest of heresies*"); the Canon Episcopi; the bulls of Popes John XXII, 1330, Innocent VIII, 1484, Alexander VI, 1494, Leo X, 1521, and Adrian VI, 1522; the Decretals of the canon law; the exorcisms of…

Comment: Google 'papal bull'  -nothing to do with the animal :)

Comment: Wikipedia is your friend - [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papal_bull)

Comment: @myanmite +1, [Papal bull](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papal_bull): an ecclesiastical edict, from the Latin *bulla*, [the seal](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulla_(seal)) on such edicts which served as evidence of their authenticity, ultimately ([purportedly](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bull&allowed_in_frame=0)) from the Gaulish *beu, "swelling or raised knob". Which makes this question General Reference.

Comment: Thanks! I did search before posting the question but had no idea that this might be a type of letter. This passage makes a lot more sense.

Comment: just fyi it's not so much a "letter" as a, uh, "law" or "declaration".

Comment: In response to this being "off-topic," I would argue that I did look in commonly-available references, but could not find what I was looking for. Now that I know exactly what this means, I know how to search for it. Once I knew that this was not some mistake or idiom, I tried with more effort to find a dictionary which actually gave the description of "papal bull" as a definition under "bull". My search yielded that only 1 in 7 dictionaries had the correct definition. The others gave no definition for "bull" other than what commonly is used for finances or animals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a reference to a papal bull:

> [Wiktionary: Papal Bull](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/papal_bull)
>
> An official document or edict from the Pope.

The unusual name actually has nothing to do with the animal, but rather derived from a Latin word meaning "boil" or "bubble". It makes reference to the particular form the the wax seal used to notarize the document.

See [here](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-papal-bull.htm) for more information on this.

Comment: Right on.  It's one of those things that would be better translated like maybe "Papal Seal" or "Papal wax"

Comment: Actually, I am pretty sure Papal bulls used lead seals, not wax.